# How Do I Get Rid Of All These Silly, Unnecessary Implementation Methods?

Tags: java

So I am making a class that is really simple. All it does is say when the mouse is clicked. So naturally I only want the mouseClicked override function. However, the IDE says I need to implement all of the methods. How do I make it so I don't need to implement all these silly, unnecessary methods?

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ME extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    public ME() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ME Me = new ME();
        Me.addMouseListener(Me);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: If your class implements MouseListener, then you are *required* to implement all its methods -- no way around that. **BUT** you *can* have your class *not* implement MouseListener and instead use an anonymous inner class that *extends* MouseAdapter. Please read the duplicate question's answers for more details on this.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: `foo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { /* your code here */ }});`

Comment: Okay thank you. I looked at the link and it worked - but only for that specific method

Comment: For instance when I try putting    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX() + e.getY());
   } inside it does not work

Comment: ??? it would work with  ***any*** of the methods that you chose to override.

Comment: The problem is for mouseMoved to work you need to add the class as a MouseMotionListener in addition to as a MouseListener.

Comment: Please see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700053/522444), one that shows how to use a class that extends MouseAdapter and is used as *both* a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener.

Comment: OH WOW I UNDERSTAND NOW THANK YOU. THAT WAS REALLY THROWING ME OFF YOU'RE THE BEST

Comment: seriously. big thank you. I completely forgot about how listeners worked

Answer (score -1):

Implementing an interface is a promise to override the methods inside it.
You can't really get away with just implementing one, although you can refrain from completing the body of the method (however this is bad practice).

Comment: Not quite true. There is an adapter class that can be used in this situation, one that uses dummy method overrides.

Comment: Well, the answer is in general correct for interfaces. For this specific case it is true that there is the adapter solution,